# Don't install anything newer than... (or an alternative approach)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dependencies

When installing packages with `apt`, one can specify the version number. I am aware of this, and I have used this feature.

I would like to know if it would instead be possible to say, "Install these packages, but only the most current version until ... ". Alternatively, perhaps I could say something like `apt update DATE`, which updates all of the repos as if I was calling `apt update` on the specified date.

I would guess that such a functionality is in principle possible because I think that the "file modified date" is stored along with the package.

Here is the scenario I envision...

I am working on a new software project. To make sure that the dependencies are correct and the environment is reproduceable, I will also set up either  a Docker image or a virtual machine. In either case, to do this, I need to see exactly what packages are already installed on my machine. So I go through the list to make note of the exact versions. Then I create an install script which installs only those packages

If you have done this, then you know that this process can be tedious because you also need to track down the dependencies and resolve all of the `The following packages have unmet dependencies:` errors.

If there was something like, `apt update DATE`, then I could essentially `freeze` the Docker container at the current date to ensure that the precise packages that I am using getting installed. Is there something like that?

Comment: That is not possible because when a new version of a package is uploaded to the repos, the previous one is normally deleted.

Comment: Freezing a Debian-based development at any point other than a standard release will indeed cause all kinds of obnoxious dependency problems. Indeed, this exact problem was one of the spurs to the creation of distros 20 years ago with repositories of single-version dependencies and standard releases.That's why Ubuntu provides two standard releases each year - so you can avoid the entire exercise and simply base upon, for example, Ubuntu Bionic or Ubuntu Cosmic.